# How to integrate Azure Web App with a VNet with gateway transit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have two VNets: **A** and **B**.
VNet **B** has a VPN gateway and connected to an on-premise network. VNet **A** is peered with VNet **B** with transit gateway enabled. This works perfectly for virtual machines. I deploy VMs to VNet **A** and can access on-premise resources from there VMs.

Now I want to deploy a Web App and connect it to VNet **A**, so the web app will have access to on-premise resources. But to do so, I need to add a VPN gateway into the network **A**, which is impossible when the network is peered with another network with *Use remote gateway* option on. But I need this option to be on to have access to on-premise resources.

What should I do? How I can give access from Web App to on-premise resources without using App Service Environment? Is it possible?

Basically, I need the combination of these two schemes
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should integrate with VNet B from the Azure web app. Also, It will be integrated with a point-to-site VPN enabled VNet. There is a new version of the VNet Integration feature that is **in preview**. It doesn't depend on point-to-site VPN. From your scenario, the web app is working like " VPN clients" in a P2S connection on the second picture.

Here are some things to keep in mind before connecting your web app to a virtual network:

> A target virtual network must have point-to-site VPN enabled with a
>   route-based gateway before it can be connected to app. The VNet must
>   be in the same subscription as your App Service Plan(ASP). The apps
>   that integrate with a VNet use the DNS that is specified for that
>   VNet.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: I saw this preview feature. Unfortunately, it doesn't support production workloads. When it will become GA I will try it.

Comment: The VNet B is managed by a different department. It is more like a hub where other departments should connect their VNets to get access to on-premise resources. Moreover, the VNet B is in a different subscription than VNet A and Web App.

Comment: If you just want to access the on-premise resource from web app, you could use [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections). One peered connection is only allowed one gateway. You could try to use VNET to VNET connection, I could not verify this on my side, maybe you can have a try.